# Get msi product name, version from command line

Tags: python, windows-installer

Is there a way to display the product name and version of a msi file from the command line? Or better yet, can this be done via python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SummaryInformation.GetProperty(PID_TITLE)` and `SummaryInformation.GetProperty(PID_REVNUMBER)` and all the other field names at [the msilib docs page](http://docs.python.org/library/msilib.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can get the product version using:

```
from msilib import *

def GetMsiProperty(path ,property):
    db = OpenDatabase(path, MSIDBOPEN_READONLY)
    view = db.OpenView ("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property='" + property + "'")
    view.Execute(None)
    result = view.Fetch()
    #print dir(result)
    return result.GetString(1)


msiVersion = GetMsiProperty(r'C:\path\to.msi' ,"ProductVersion")
```

Your python version must be higher than 2.5 for the above function to work.